# truthy and falsy statement with detach function

Tags: jquery

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bLCcz/)

html...

```
<p>Hello</p> 
how are 
<p>you?</p>
<button>Attach/detach paragraphs</button>
```

jquery...

```
var p;
$("button").click(function(){
  if ( p ) {
    p.appendTo("body");
    p = null;
  } else {
    p = $("p").detach();//paragraph is removed so p returns null but how is it truthy?
  }
});
```

I couldn't understand how the truthy and falsy statements are working here.

Also, if I add true boolean to p `if( p=1){` then it wouldn't suppose to be run exactly same as above.

So, it's not just about truthy and falsy statement here but more than this.

I'll be glad if anyone can give me the clear concept on this.

Comment: unclear what you are asking

Comment: @ArunPJohny I mean in else statement paragraph is removed so p should be falsy but it's returning truthy so I'm wondering about how this is working.

Comment: @NavinRauniyar the paragraph is removed and assigned back to the variable `p`, did you notice that.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to understand the following diagram carefully:

```
                             first click      second click          third click
var p; //falsy---------------        |             |
$("button").click(function(){  |     |             V                       |
  if ( p ) { //if truthy       | ----|   < ------|----p is appended        |
    p.appendTo("body");        |     |           |                         |
    p = null; //return falsy   |     V           |--// p returns falsy--   V
  } else { //if falsy          ---|--- run this  |     <------|-------run this
    p = $("p").detach();  -----OK detached // p returns truthy
  }                          |---- returns truthy or falsy 
                               not because of $(p) has text or not 
                                but because of p has function or null
```

And for your second question, when you add `p=1` it becomes boolean but within the else statement it's returning the function not a boolean means if you just put `p`  within if condition then only `p` will become truthy and return if condition as if it's variable was declared firstly to nothing and after else condition variable `p` is defined and returned truthy. **So it's all about truthy and falsy statement.**

You'll also be wondering how `p.appendTo("body");` is appending the text but if you read the documentation on [detach](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) then you'll know that by using detach function it is capable to add the text back again. So, p is returning `$("p").detach();` in else condition and thus now it's returning `$("p").detach().appendTo("body");` in if condition and it's why showing the text back again.

Comment: I don't even know if the answer is correct, upvote (+1) just for creating an ASCII diagram in under 20 minutes from question being asked... kudos to you find sir or maam.

Comment: @erikrunia Hereafter I am also going to draw fancy diagrams. :)

Comment: sorry Raj, i have upvoted you as well so my vote doesn't unfairly benefit one or the other... his ASCII just made me smile

Answer (score 1):

In javascript `NULL`,`UNDEFINED`,`0` are being considered as `false`. In your case initially the value of `P` will be `null`, So the control flow points to the `else` statement. And after finishing the else statement, the value of `P` will be some `Jquery object`, so the next time the `if` condition becomes `true` and it will go inside of that `if` statement. and vice versa.